# Webservice for IBM FileNet

Tags: c#, web-services, filenet-p8, filenet

I plan to integrate parts of the IBM Filenet archiv solution into my ASP.NET web application.

Perhaps in a framework or something like that.

Has anyone experience with that or does anyone know that there is the possibility to call a  webservice?

Best Regards

Comment: Asking to recommend a tool is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM FileNet offer Java and .Net API to connect either the Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) or Web Services Interoperability (WSI) protocols.

see for more details:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.p8.common.dev.doc%2Fdev_roadmap%2Ftools.htm

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/classify/v8r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.classify.ccenter.doc%2Fbnrgs003.htm